# Dúvida quanto a Request.Form

Tags: c#

O que é o Request.Form? Como eu interpreto essas linhas?

```
if (Request.Form["chkTornarObrigatorio"] != null)
                                    ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio = int.Parse(Request.Form["chkTornarObrigatorio"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

**[*Request*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRequest(v=vs.110).aspx)** é uma classe do ASP.NET que permite a leitura de valores enviados durante uma requisição Web.

> O que é Request.Form?

É uma propriedade ([***Request.Form***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx)) da classe Request que você pode utilizar para recuperar os valores dos elementos de formulário postados no corpo da solicitação HTTP.

> Como eu interpreto essas linhas?

```
//Com base no nome do elemento do seu formulário,
//verifica se o campo chkTornarObrigatorio não está nulo
if (Request.Form["chkTornarObrigatorio"] != null)
{
    //Caso não esteja nulo, converte o valor do campo chkTornarObrigatorio 
    //para o tipo inteiro e associa a ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio
    ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio = int.Parse(Request.Form["chkTornarObrigatorio"]);
}
```

Dê uma olhada dos links que adicionei para maiores detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

O `Request.Form` é usado para obter informações de um submit de um formulário HTML que foi enviado via POST. Como a informação do POST é invisível ao usuário, você deve recuperar através do método Request.

A linha em questão é interpretada da seguinte maneira:

```
//O campo chkTornarObrigatorio foi enviado pelo formulário de uma outra página via post, nesta linha verificamos se ele está preenchido
if (Request.Form["chkTornarObrigatorio"] != null)
{
    //Se o campo existir, nós pegamos o valor do campo e convertemos para inteiro a
    ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio = int.Parse(Request.Form["chkTornarObrigatorio"]);
}
```

Basicamente, você está buscando o valor que foi enviado de outra página, veja [este link](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp) como referência.